# Spring combining global and gateway filters - global not executing after gateway filter

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm quite new with spring cloud gateway and currently trying to setup global filters and gateway one to run for a specific route.
The problem which I encountered, is that by some reason my global filter (Vary) does not execute after the execution of the gateway filter.

I implemented **Ordered** interface for all of them and if to exclude the gateway filter from the route - everything works as expected.
Below is an example of the filter structure:

Vary filter (global) works as post-filter, executes fine if gateway filter not included into the chain. Has an order = -1.

CORS filter (global) works as pre-filter and executed successfully (as first pre-filter in chain). Has an order = 0.

Custom gateway filter (applied to route through yml). Executes fine, though seems to not passing response down the chain for post-filtering to Vary filter. Has an order = 10;

I kept the gateway filter basic just to see will it pass the response down the chain:

```java
@Component
public class TestGatewayFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<TestGatewayFilter.Config> implements Ordered {

    public TestGatewayFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 10;
    }

    public static class Config {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Specifying the gateway filter in yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: servicev1
          uri: http://service-app:8888
          predicates:
            - Path=/sgateway/service/v1/**
          filters:
            - name: TestGatewayFilter
```

The Vary filter implements **GlobalFilter** interface and contains the following method:

```java
@Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(exchange)
            .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> addResponseHeaders(exchange.getRequest(),exchange.getResponse())));
    }
```

The current behavior (when having gateway filter enabled for the route) is that Vary global filter does not execute and 500 error returned.

If only global filters are in chain CORS executed first (as pre) and then the Vary (as post)

Would really appreciate if someone can point me what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

closing the question as just realised an issue unrelated to the filters, but which was blocking the response to come down the chain.

Works as expected.

P.S. system was not able to resolve and reach the other service as I did not specify it to check on localhost.